# boost::spirit (classic): difference between | and ^?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Doc says (spirit classic):

`a | b, Union, Match a or b. Also referred to as alternative`

`a ^ b, XOR, Match a or b, but not both.`

Can anybody give me practical example when it matters?

**EDIT**: Give me practical example, please. Create rule, use some actors, parse something and show me the difference. I know what OR and XOR is, but I don't see any difference in boost::spirit result between | and ^.

`std::string t;
boost::spirit::classic::rule<> r = ( ch_p( 'a' ) ^ ch_p( 'b' ) )[ assign_a( t ) ];
//boost::spirit::classic::rule<> r = ( ch_p( 'a' ) | ch_p( 'b' ) )[ assign_a( t ) ];
boost::spirit::classic::parse( "when it matters?", r );`

Comment: it always matters OR is just something different than XOR

Comment: The question is too vague.

Comment: They're very different operations. `1 | 1 == 1`, while `1 ^ 1 == 0`. They have very different implications too.

Comment: Invent a pair of parsers that can *both* match the input.  For example (in RE terms:  `ab*`  and `a*b`) *THEN* you will see the difference.

Comment: Look at [this test](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/classic/test/operators_tests.cpp#L112) where the "alternatives" are a letter and an hexadecimal digit.

Comment: @llonesmiz Now I see, thank you! Put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Bogdan I think you should do the work here. Alternatively you could retract the question.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `^` (XOR) in `boost::spirit` creates 'exclusive or' combination of parsers. I didn't get it because I stuck the subject into str_p/ch_p parsers.

Credits to @llonesmiz from whom I got the best example:

`parse( "Z", alpha_p ^ xdigit_p );`